# Federate data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel

So I have a packing list, which I have partitioned into separate sheets by category, so each sheet looks something like:

```
Item | Quantity | Box Number  
hat  | 2        | 1
```

So what I want is a 'master' sheet where all my items are listed across all sheets, so that I can sort by box number. This should cater for additions in the sheets and reflect that automatically in the master sheet. I tried copy and paste with links but that doesn't allow for additional rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot table you can achieve this. Please follow the below steps

1. Create a Master Sheet and place your cursor at A1 cell
2. Press Alt+D and then P
3. you will get pivote table and pivot chart wizard
4. Select 'Multiple Consolidation Ranges' option
5. Click on Next
6. Select 'Create a single page field for me' option
7. Click on Next
8. Click on 'Range' edit box at the top
9. Select the first sheet where you have your first set of data
10. Select all the range that you wanted to include. You can include as many as empty row at the bottom
11. CLick on 'Add' Button.
12. Select the next sheet you wanted to add into your master sheet
13. Repeat the steps from 10 till all your sheets are included
14. At the end click 'Next'
15. Select 'Existing worksheet' option
16. Click on 'Finish'
17. If you want to add additional sheet you may need to repeat these steps again.
18. If you are adding any data into any of the sheet, then you need to click on 'Refresh All' from the 'Data' Ribbon, which will refresh the added data.
19. You can hide or filter unwanted columns and rows from the pivot
20. Or you can refer all required cells of this pivot sheet to new sheet. Only issue is you need keep clicking 'Refresh All' from Data Tab on the ribbon everytime there is a change.

Now all your data are in your master sheet

You can also do this using Microsoft Query option found in Data Tab-->From Other sources.